# windows 7 task bar not showing active tasks

Tags: windows-7, taskbar

Just got new PC at work. Still running windows 7 Enterprise like the previous Windows PC.

However, when I launch an application, no icon appears on the task bar. Not even when I minimize the app. I can still get to the app via Alt-Tab.

The icons between the Windows button and the system tray are all "launch only". Even when the associated app is running, clicking on the icon launches a new instance.

The task bar is not locked and no tool bars are enabled.

I've tried every option I can find, but nothing works. Other users have looked and have no idea, Neither does our PC support team.

I would have included a screen picture, but I don't have a personal hosting account and work blocks me from accessing image hosting sites.

Comment: If another user logs into that computer, does it behave the same way?  How about if you boot into Safe Mode?

Comment: Booting to Safe Mode didn't make a difference. Will ask a coworker to try logging in. (All PCs were replaced with new ones, so everyone is busy working on getting back to work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be a problem with your profile, which may be corrupted 
[Technet: Open programs not appearing on taskbar](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/open-programs-not-appearing-on-taskbar/c1059fe8-92b5-4396-99d8-2aa00102cdad?auth=1)

Microsoft outline steps to fix a corrupted user profile.. [link](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/fix-corrupted-user-profile#1TC=windows-7)

You can also use these steps to troubleshoot to see if the issue is isolated to you 
 - See if the issue is only happening to you
 
- Have another user Logging into your workstation to see if the same issue occurs
 
- Logging into another workstation to see if the same issue occurs

Comment: Thanks. Once I told the PC support team what you said, they were able to recreate my user profile. That fixed the problem.